# How to backup a game DVD on hard disk in ISO format?

Tags: backup, dvd, copy-protection

I need to make a backup for a game that I own on DVD (Imperivm 3), making an ISO from it on my hard disk.
I already made a backup of another game using CDBurnerXP and it worked fine.
However, when I tried with Imperivm 3, CDBurnerXP worked until 95% and then gave me an error: "Burning error occured" and it stops. When I check the CDBurnerXP log, it says "Error occured: Internal SDK error:"

I am not sure why that happened:

- the DVD is not working well
- the DVD is protected

If the DVD is a bit scratched, maybe the missing data is not important (a bmp image or something), so if there are missing 20 KB, filling them with 0 might be ok, game would work the same with or without that data. The question is if there is any program capable to ignore the errors and create the ISO anyways.

If the DVD is ok but there is a copy protection, then what kind of programs I have to use in order to backup the DVD? (programs that can crack/skip the protection). I found "Game Jackal Pro" (SlySoft) and I wonder how good it is, if there are better programs and if there are any free alternatives.

Comment: Try to burn the at the lowest speed.
It worked for me after I had the same issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

gnu ddrescue is designed to work in such situations - its a dd style tool designed specifically for data recovery. You'll need to boot into linux (maybe with a liveusb to use it).

[Howtogeek](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/21876/rescue-old-damaged-cds-with-an-ubuntu-live-cd/) suggests running two passes - the first  is
`ddrescue -n -b 2048 /dev/cdrom <ISO file> <log file>`
which backs up the easy to recove parts of the disk, and a second
`ddrescue -d -b 2048 /dev/cdrom <ISO file> <log file>` which adds harder to recover blocks

Comment: And Windows users complain that Macs have no software. Sillies. All the REALLY good stuff is on *nix.

Comment: as far as forensics goes, yeah. I keep an up to date linux partition for dealing with stuff like this.

Answer (score 1):

install `cygwin` from [here](http://cygwin.com) and install `mksiofs` into `cygwin`(however if i remember it installed by default), Then use `mkisofs` from command line.

Answer (score 0):

Blindread/Blindwrite was designed for such things.

Note that the SDK error stands for "Software Development Kit", and suggests an error in the software.  Even if you have a bad disc, that should result in the hardware issuing a complaint to the software and the software should handle that gracefully, not by having an error.  So, it seems you encountered a bug in the software (which might or might not have been encouraged by something like a bad disc).