# Cant copy some files from dvd drive

Tags: usb, freeze, dvd

I tried adding those files into .zip file, I tried to copy them, I tried installing a game the right way by clicking Install but always the computer freezes, shows error: not responding .. Is there any other way to copy those files into my computer?

I dont know if the problem is with my dvd drive or the dvd disk.
My dvd drive is usb external dvd drive.

Comment: Try the "Isobuster" software to backup the disc and then install. The software have the ability to zerofill or omit the bad sectors.

Answer (score 0):

Your first try is to use another DVD drive. If it works right off the bat, the problem's with your drive. If it has trouble, then the problem's with the disc.

If you can't get the file off the disc that way, then there's one other possibility. Keep trying to copy the file repeatedly. You may get lucky and the data may resolve.

There's also gnu ddrescue as talked about in this answer:
[How to backup a game DVD on hard disk in ISO format?](https://superuser.com/questions/662900/how-to-backup-a-game-dvd-on-hard-disk-in-iso-format)